# Logback appender and Postfix

Tags: java, email, postfix-mta, logback, appender

I'm trying to create an appender that filters any logs below ERROR level and sends e-mails with these logs.
This is how my logback.xml file looks like (just the appender part):

```
<appender name="EMAIL" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <!-- deny all events with a level below ERROR -->
        <level>ERROR</level>
    </filter>
    <smtpHost>${smtpHost}</smtpHost>
    <smtpPort>${smtpPort}</smtpPort>
    <STARTTLS>true</STARTTLS>
    <username>${username}</username>
    <password>${password}</password>
    <to>${mailingList}</to>

    <from>${username}</from>
    <subject>%logger{20} - %m</subject>
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.html.HTMLLayout"/>
    <cyclicBufferTracker class="ch.qos.logback.core.spi.CyclicBufferTrackerImpl">
          <bufferSize>1</bufferSize>
    </cyclicBufferTracker>
</appender>
```

Where `smtpHost` is localhost and `username` and `password` belongs to a user I've created on the server that runs the application.
It doesn't seem to work - no email was sent.

But, when I parameter for another server, i.e, `smtpHost = smtp.gmail.com`, I get the emails as expected.

I guess that means something's wrong in the way I've configured postfix on the server.
I would be happy to post here any information from the `main.cf` file ( I simply don't want to post it all ).

Comment: I don't use logback myself, but I presume that it can be configured to emit internal debugging info. I'd try enabling that to see if you can get the actual error seen by the SMTP appender.

Answer (score 1):

It's a long shot but here is an idea. Posfix is often configured to reject emails from senders not issuing a valid helo_hostname. Does postfix's main.ch have directive similar to the following?

```
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
        reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname,
        reject_invalid_helo_hostname

smtpd_sender_restrictions = 
        reject_non_fqdn_sender,
        reject_unknown_sender_domain
```

If so, you may want to set the `localhost` property of [SMTPAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SMTPAppender) to a reasonable value. By the the way, `${username}` should probably not be used to set both `<from>` and `<username>` for postfix.

BYW, it is almost always a good idea to set the `debug` attribute of `<configuration>` element to `true` to see logback's internal messages on the console. As in:

```
<configuration debug="true">...</configuration>
```